# ¿Como puede un template de una app extender de una base que esta en otra app diferente en Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django

No logro entender como funciona ni porque se puede, extender un archivo **' html '** de un **' base.html '** de otra applicacion diferente de la cual reside, en si esa es la intención, lo hice de adrede pero no se como funciona ni porque se puede hacer eso.

¿Es acaso que **Django** si no encuentra en la app donde se encuentra el archivo **' html '** el **' base.html '** busca por default en la otra app? o algo así?

Así empieza el archivo(*el **'template tag'** de extendido, creo que se llama...*) **' html '** que extiende de **' base.html '** de la otra app:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
```

La estructura de la carpeta **' templates '** donde se encuentra el archivo **' base.html '** es la siguiente (*por se acaso*):

```
|─── templates
|    |─── core
|    |    |─── base.html
|    |    └─── (mas archivos html)
```

La estructura de la carpeta **' templates '** donde se encuentra el archivo **' html '** que extiende de **' base.html '** es el mismo, solo cambia el nombre de la sub-carpeta y no tine un **' base.html '**.

También tengo la duda si ¿Es de buena practica esto?

---

**Desde ya gracias por sus respuestas!**

Answer (score 1):

Esto se debe a que el encargado de recuperar los templates HTML es un mismo recurso denominado `loader`, que puede estar configurado para buscar en una serie de directorios y bajo un jerarquía especifica.

Por ejemplo, de forma predeterminada, el archivo `settings.py` está configurado para buscar templates dentro de las apps, y otra carpeta en la raíz del proyecto, con esta ultima podrías sobrescribir los templates de otras apps, dentro del tutorial inicial de Django se hace esto para personalizar el titulo de las páginas de administración.

Es por esto, que para evitar que las plantillas entren en conflicto se recomienda que cuando tengas una carpeta template dentro de una app, pongas otra carpeta adentro de esta repitiendo el nombre de la app.

Esto se debe a que el encargado de recuperar los templates HTML es un mismo recurso denominado `loader`, que puede estar configurado para buscar en una serie de directorios y bajo un jerarquia especifica.

Por ejemplo, de forma predeterminada, el archivo `settings.py` está configurado para buscar templates dentro de las apps, y otra carpeta en la raíz del proyecto, con esta ultima podrías sobrescribir los templates de otras apps, dentro del tutorial inicial de Django se hace esto para personalizar el titulo de las páginas de administración.

Es por esto, que para evitar que las plantillas entren en conflicto se recomienda que cuando tengas una carpeta template dentro de una app, pongas otra carpeta adentro de esta repitiendo el nombre de la app.

Para una mayor referencia te dejo unos enlaces a la documentación:

- [Loader types](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/api/#template-loaders)
- [Configuración de templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#templates)
- [Tutorial donde se sobrescribe el template del administrador](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial07/#customizing-your-project-s-templates)

Comment: Quién recomienda eso ?... Pycharm por defecto crea una carpeta principal llamado `templates` y la toma como carpeta principal para .html, luego de ahí puedes crear subcarpetas con los nombres de tu app. Quién llena una sola carpeta que esté tus views, tu model, tu url(tus conf) y aparte tus templates... No lo veo conveniente. Pero bueno, es depende de cada uno.

Comment: @JeanpierreRivas Piensa en una app como un modulo reutilizable, que tiene templates asociados, por lo que debe estar dentro de la misma estructura. En mi caso parece mucho más cómodo y organizado el que todos los elementos del app tanto `templates`, `static`, `views`, etc. particularmente cuando se trata de un proyecto grande con numerosas apps

Comment: Cómo digo, es un punto en el que se siente cómodo cada uno. Pero no recomiendo la verdad. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841764/best-practice-for-django-project-working-directory-structure

Answer (score 0):

> {% extends 'core/base.html' %}

¿Qué significa esto? Esto significa que puede usar las mismas partes de su HTML para diferentes páginas de su sitio web.

Las plantillas le ayudan cuando desea usar la misma información o diseño en más de un lugar. No tienes que repetirte en cada archivo. Y si desea cambiar algo, no tiene que hacerlo en cada plantilla, ¡solo una!

En tu `settings.py` existe una configuración `default`

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n',  # translate
            ],
        },
    },
```

templates viene a ser tu carpeta principal

```
|─── templates
|    |─── core
|    |    |─── base.html
|    |    └─── (mas archivos html)
|    |─── example
|    |    |─── base_example.html
|    |    └─── (mas archivos html)
|    |─── base_principal.html
```

Para extender otra plantilla base sólo tiene que poner la carpeta que sigue después de la carpeta `templates`

en este caso sería

```
{% extends 'example/base_example.html' %}
```

Y si tu html base principal se encuentra en la carpeta principal `templates`

deberás sólo extender el html

```
{% extends 'base_principal.html' %}
```